# Django User specific page

Tags: django, django-models

I m creating a Leave Web Application. I want to show each user's leave status according to the user who is logged in.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



types_of_leaves = (
    ('Sick Leave', 'Sick Leave'),
    ('Earned Leave', 'Earned Leave'),
    ('Annual Leave', 'Annual Leave'),
)   
# Create your models here.
class LeaveApp(models.Model):
    authuser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fdate = models.DateField()
    tdate=models.DateField()
    type_of_leave=models.CharField(max_length=20 ,choices =types_of_leaves, default = "" )
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.reason
    
    
class Sick_leave(models.Model):
    leave=models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.leave
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly is your question? Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask]

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly

Comment: I m working on a leave app. In that, if a user is logged in he/she can request leave and can see that leave status in the form of a table where the user can see if the leave is approved or not. The problem is - when a user login the user can see all the leave applications for other users too. I want a user to see his own data. How can i make this work ?